# Directory error when trying to do migrations using typeorm (node)

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I'm trying to do migration with my typeorm but I'm trying an error directing the path to my migrations and getting the error

```
No changes in database schema were found - cannot generate a migration. To create a new empty migration use "typeorm migration:create" command
```

My folders in src:

```
database
   -config.ts
entities
   -User.ts
app.ts
server.ts
```

config.ts (datasource)

```
import { DataSource } from "typeorm"
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: "postgres",
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: 5432,
    username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
    synchronize: true,
    logging: true,
    entities: [`${__dirname}/**/entities/*.{ts,js}`],
    migrations: [`${__dirname}/**/database/migrations/*.{ts,js}`],
})
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "authapi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --exec ts-node ./src/server.ts",
    "migration:generate": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs -d ./src/database/config.ts migration:generate ./src/database/migrations/default",
    "migration:run": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs -d ./src/database/config.ts migration:run"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.6.4",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.2",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/nodemon": "^1.19.2",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
    "pg": "^8.7.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.7"
  }
}
```

The error occurs after the "npm run migrate:generate", my goal is to create a migrations folder inside database automatically.

User entity

```
import { BeforeInsert, BeforeUpdate, Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

@Entity('users')
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column({
        default: false,
    })
    isActivate: boolean;

    @Column()
    username: string;

    @Column()
    email: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;

    @Column({
        default: ''
    })
    tokenActivate: string;

    @Column({
        default: ''
    })
    tokenResetPass: string;


    @BeforeInsert()
    @BeforeUpdate()
    hashPassword() {
        this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, 8);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically you are right, the following is considered an error because it returns exit code 1

```
No changes in database schema were found - cannot generate a migration. To create a new empty migration use "typeorm migration:create" command
```

I don't know why you think this has something to do with the folder or path.

`migration:generate` only(!) creates a migration file if your entities found in `` entities: [`${__dirname}/**/entities/*.{ts,js}`] `` contains any change compared to your databse.

Make a change for a test in `src/entities/User.ts` like adding a column and then generate it via `npm run migrate:generate`. Eventually the file be created as `src/database/migrations/default.ts`

If you want to create a new empty migration to write changes that updates inserted data and have nothing to do with the database structure, use `migration:create` https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/using-cli#create-a-new-migration

EDIT: Answer after the discussion. `__dirname` points to the folder where the current file lives. The entities location relative to the `config.ts` is `` entities: [`${__dirname}/../entities/*.{ts,js}\`], ``

Comment: Still the error persists, I already checked in my admin pg to see if something had already been created and there is nothing.

Comment: This has nothing do with an admin interface or your database itself. `migration:generate` creates a file on your file system! Also you have `synchronize: true` as option, so your database and entities are synced anyways when you recompile and restart your backend

Comment: Yeah, but that's not happening lol. The weirdest thing is that I watched a video from a youtube tutorial where the guy did the exact same thing and it worked, but not for me.

Comment: In addition to having already done exactly the same as the documentation, so the only problem I can see is in the entity directory "    entities: [`${__dirname}/**/entities/*.{ts,js}`],", but I can't really pinpoint the error, the folder looks correct to me.

Comment: Well, I came to the conclusion that the problem is not really in the path, because even though I import User directly inside the entity in the datasource, it returns the same error

Comment: Can you query the database within your code via the repository belonging to the UserEntity? Also show your database and the changed entity.

Comment: Do you mean to show the User.ts code? Within entities folder?

Comment: Yes + the database because I would like to see what is the difference in the schema

Comment: I updated the post. What do you mean show the database? I am using postgres by pgadmin

Comment: Like my post said: There need to be a difference between the schema and the entity. Which column of the above entity is not present in the postgres database?

Comment: All of them, actually the "User" table was not created. This is the application's first migration

Comment: Let's move over to a chat topic because it's annoying to do this in the comments https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247105/discussing-https-stackoverflow-com-q-73263931-6459327